# Subtract accumulated values in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subtraction, accumulate

I have one ATM machine that has information below:

```
-   --Date-----|--Withdraw---|---CashLoad
-   01/15/13--|----10----------|-------300
-   01/16/13--|----20
-   01/17/13--|----50
-   01/18/13--|---120
-   01/19/13--|----20----------|-------400
-   01/20/13--|----60
-   01/21/13--|----80
-   01/22/13--|----50
-   01/23/13--|----90----------|------300
```

I want to calculate the end-of-day balance for that ATM, this balance equals to the CashLoad - accumulated Withdraw amounts of each day. If the ATM is reloaded, the process starts over again

Here is what I'm looking for:

```
-   --Date------|--Withdraw---|------CashLoad---|--------EOD_Balance
-   01/15/13---|----10----------|-------300-----------|-----------290
-   01/16/13---|----20----------|-----------------------|-----------270
-   01/17/13---|----50----------|-----------------------|-----------220
-   01/18/13---|---120---------|------------------------|----------100
-   01/19/13---|----20----------|-------400-----------|-----------380
-   01/20/13---|----60----------|-----------------------|-----------320
-   01/21/13---|----80----------|-----------------------|-----------240
-   01/22/13---|----50----------|-----------------------|-----------190
-   01/23/13---|----90----------|-------300-----------|-----------210
```

This is the query I am currently using:

```
select
    tmp1.atminternalid, tmp1.date,
    tmp1.CashLoad - tmp1.accum_disp as cashbalafterload
from mytable as tmp1 where SettlementDate = (select max(SettlementDate)
from DM_ADMIN.dbo.temptable1001 as tmp2
where tmp2.ATMInternalID = tmp1.atminternalid )
order by tmp1.atminternalid
```

How do I change my query to get the results I am looking for?

Comment: What are you currently trying?

Comment: I created another column called accum_Wtd then I tried to use the CashLoad to subtract those values. It doesn't work yet. select tmp1.atmid, tmp1.date, tmp1.CashLoad - tmp1.accum_wtd as cashbalance
from mytable as tmp1
where Date = (select max(Date)
                        from mytable as tmp2
                        where tmp2.ATMID = tmp1.ATMID
                        )
order by tmp1.ATMID

Comment: Added the query to the question since it's vital to know. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 doesn't have a cumulative sum function.  You can solve this with a correlated subquery:

```
select atm.*,
       (select sum(cashload) - sum(withdraw)
        from atm atm2
        where atm2.date <= atm.date
       ) as EOD_Balance
from atm;
```

EDIT:

Well, that does change the problem.  You need to sum from the date of the previous cash load:

```
select atm.*,
       (select sum(cashload) - sum(withdraw)
        from atm atm3
        where atm3.date <= atm.date and
              atm3.date >= CashLoadDate
       ) as EOD_Balance
from (select atm.*,
             (select max(date)
              from atm atm2
              where atm2.date <= atm.date and
                    cashload > 0
             ) as CashLoadDate
      from atm
     ) atm;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, Gordon. However, i forgot to mention that before the new cash load, they took out the remaining cash first and then load the new amount into the ATM. For example:
on 01/18/13, remaining cash was $100, on 01/19/13, they took away that $100, put in $400, and the EOD_Balance now $380 ($400-$20) not ($400+$100-$20)

Comment: I tried it but got a few error messages. Can you please help?
Thank you, Gordon!
Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
The column prefix 'atm' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "atm.date" could not be bound.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 14
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'atm'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'date'.

Comment: @user3221030 . . . Here is an example of the code working in SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/28810).  This is exactly the same code in the answer.

Comment: I got it, Gordon! Thank you so much for your help!